# Crud repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

у меня есть 3 класса:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class WeatherNote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @JsonAlias("name")
    private String cityName;
    private Date dateOfRequest = new Date();
    private Double temperature;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "weather_list")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonFromOpenWeatherMap extends WeatherNote {
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "weather_list")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonFromGismeteo extends WeatherNote {
}
```

и репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface WeatherNoteRepo extends CrudRepository<WeatherNote, Long> {

    <S extends WeatherNote> S save(S entity);

}
```

получается происходит запись в одну таблицу, все работает нормально.
Вопрос как сделать теперь чтение из таблицы? перепробовал уже кучу способов ничего не работает

```
Iterable<WeatherNote> findAll();
```

не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает? Тут Ванги сидят, по вашему?

Comment: пишет что WeatherNote not an entity

Comment: По моему `@MappedSuperclass` не помечает класс как `Entity`, вот тут написано что [таблицы для суперкласса не существует](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html). Вам нужно делать `CrudRepository<JsonFromGismeteo, Long>` и подобный для `JsonFromOpenWeatherMap`. Либо писать свой класс-репозиторий инжектить в него `EntityManager` и писать запросы.